# Count by hour interval

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

i have written an SQL query  in postgresql that works fine it gets me the number of work done per  employee for every hour

```
SELECT COUNT(work_done) AS count, EXTRACT(hour from start_time) AS hour
FROM c_call
WHERE  start_time >= '2018-10-13 00:00:00'
GROUP BY employee_id;
```

it's perfect  if an emplyee was actif ine every interval hour but when an hour has no data for an employee it is omitted . how can make it work so that  the result contains a row for each interval with the value field set to zero if the employee didnt work at that hour.

Comment: A row with 0 for every non-worked hour? That will be a lot of rows.

Comment: yes but i can then process that data elsewhere ( i only need the data for the day so it wont be too much rows )

Comment: What exactly is the point of such a return value? That's not something that's particularly easy to do in SQL, and honestly, I'm struggling to think of why you'd want to do so here as opposed to application logic.

Comment: it's because i need to display this data in a google table chart and for the google table chart i need to specify each column value ( the google table chart is drawn dynamically ) so it would be much easier to send data like that

Comment: Have a help table (or recursive cte) with a row for each hour. Right join that table.

Comment: how can i perform this query ? ( i'm not that advanced in sql ) i dont have the write permission in the database so i can create a table to do so

Comment: You want a table that will have a row for each hour/empolyee combination? Or one row per hour containing an array with each employee worked time?

Comment: i was thinking for a row for each hour/empolyee combination

Comment: the table strucutre is   Employee_ID-- Work_done-- start_time

Comment: I am getting this syntax error: `ERROR: column "c_call.start_time" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate a hour series using [generate_series](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html) function:

```
SELECT * FROM generate_series(0, 23) AS foo(bar)
```

And then use it to fill the hour gaps:

```
WITH employee_call AS (
    SELECT 
        COUNT(work_done) AS count, 
        EXTRACT(hour from start_time) AS hour_fraction
    FROM 
        c_call
    WHERE  
        start_time >= '2018-10-13 00:00:00'
    GROUP BY 
        employee_id
), hour_series (hour_fraction) AS (
    SELECT generate_series(0, 23)
)
SELECT 
    COALESCE(c.count, 0) AS count, 
    COALESCE(c.hour_fraction, h.hour_fraction) AS hour_fraction 
FROM 
    hour_series h 
    LEFT JOIN employee_call c ON (c.hour_fraction = h.hour_fraction)
```